# Which one to use: DirectX? Windows Media Player? GNU? Others?

Tags: c#, directshow, directx-9, windows-media-player

I want to create a windows Forms program where I play an AVI file.
I want to be able to play it in full speed, to pause, to get the total number of frames, and to show a given frame (seek).
The AVI file has metadata for the file AND metadata per frame.

I want to do this in a windows Forms application in C#, or if it is really necessary using C++.
Internet search shows me a lot of possibilities to use: DirectX, DirectShow, Windows Media Player, Microsoft DirectX9, GNU code, and several other methods.

Alas I haven't seen one that supports all that I want, especially the metadata per frame is not used often.

It seems that several of these methods are obsolete, for instance to be able to use Microsoft DirectX I need to add "useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy".

So anyone who knows what method is the latest and greatest method to use in windows programming? Which method allows me to show metadate-per-frame?

Comment: You formulate question a bit wrong (can be flagged as opinion-based). Googling for `c# metadata-per-frame avi` gives [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/3eabf903-b49f-4f92-b508-f28a795d6c90/microsoft-expression-encoder-4-faq?forum=encoder).

Comment: DirectX is a collection of APIs: Direct3d, Direct2d, DirectWrite, DXGI and others. DirectShow is also part of DirectX. DirectShow can do the things you describe, also it has bindings for C#. What metadata actually you want to extract from the frames?